# How to show a List with condition in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a list that shows all data selected from database. Now I want to implement a condition to select and show data list for the current DateTime only.

Example: show a List where `List.year = DateTime().year`.

How should I code to make something like that?

```
class CustomListView extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;

  CustomListView(this.spacecrafts);

  Widget build(context) {

  return ListView.builder(

     itemCount: spacecrafts.length,

     itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {

      return createViewItem(spacecrafts[currentIndex], context);

     },
   ); 
  }

   Widget createViewItem(Spacecraft spacecraft, BuildContext context) {

        var itemDate = spacecraft.startDate;
        var currentDate =  new DateTime.now() ;

        return new ListTile(
                       .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to filter the list, either when you fetch it from database or using `where`, like this:

```dart
class FilteredListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final int year;
  final List<Spacecraft> filteredSpacecrafts;

  CustomListView(List<Spacecraft> allSpacecrafts, this.year) : 
    filteredSpacecrafts = allSpacecrafts.where(
      (spacecraft) => spacecraft.year == year).toList();

  Widget build(context) {

  return ListView.builder(

     itemCount: filteredSpacecrafts.length,

     itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {

      return createViewItem(filteredSpacecrafts[currentIndex], context);

     },
   ); 
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have two options.

1. Select the data with condition applied
2. Select the whole data from the database and filter it before the display.

You can choose whatever is most suited for your project.

There are ways to filter the list. Example :

```
_resignedEmployees = allEmployees.where((emp) => emp.isResigned).toList();
```

You can also prepare a separate list and show. Sample code below :

```
allEmployees.forEach((f) {

   if (f.name == _searchText) {
     _searchList.add(f);
   }
   return _searchList ;
}
```